# How to edit DataGridView and send change back to Entity (LINQ)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagridview, entity

I have WF project and this code:

```
public static void fillDataGridUsers(string inDepartment, DataGridView outList)
    {
        var query = context.Users.Where(g => g.SubDepartment.Department.DepartmentName == inDepartment).Select(i =>
        new UsersForEdit
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Login = i.Login
        });
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = query;
        outList.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    }
    private class UsersForEdit 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
    }
```

I can edit DataGridView, but cant save this.

```
private void SaveGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Core.ControlPanel.Manager.saveGridUsers();
    }

public static void saveGridUsers()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

If i load only Entity table - all good.
When i try load with new {} i got only ReadOnly DataGridView,
When i try create my table with data what i want, i cant send it back or create some link.

for example i need
new UsersForEdit
            {
                Id = i.Id,
                Login = i.Login,
                Department = i.Department.DepartmentName
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can edit DataGridView, but cant save this

Context tracks changes only for entities, that were materialized (as a query results) using this context, or were added/attached to it. When you're making any projection, that is, transforming query results via `Select`, you're getting entities, that are not related to the context.

Hence, there is no change tracking here. When user modifies `UsersForEdit` instance, no changes will be pushed back to the context. In fact, `SaveChanges` makes no sense in this scenario.

> When i try load with `new {}` i got only ReadOnly DataGridView

Instances of anonymous types are immutable. This:

```
var foo = new { A = 1, B = "bar" };
```

ultimately compiles into code like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly int _a;
    private readonly string _b;

    public Foo(int a, string b)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
    }

    public int A { get { return _a; } }
    public string B { get { return _b; } }
}
```

As as result, you can't change properties of anonymous type, and grid view is read only.

To achieve what you want, you need to push changes back to the context.
This can solved using several approaches. E.g., in disconnected scenario (when context is thrown away after loading data) you can track changes yourself: remember somewhere changed entities, and, when you need to save changes, load entities by id using new context, and apply changes from view models (`UsersForEdit` instances).

Comment: Can i modify private class UsersForEdit and set set{} and get{} for send canges?

Comment: Actually, it depends on lifetime of the context. If the context lives as long, as view lives, you can write some code to send changes from `UsersForEdit` to appropriate `User`. If context is created per-operation (e.g., load and save uses separate context instances), you need a way to remember, what was changed, and re-apply changes to the `User` later.